# Native Tizen Wearable 3.0 Calling Webservice

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

We are developing an Tizen 3.0 native wearable application. We need to call an REST webservice to upload some data. I cant find any good guides or documentation howto do it?

As far as we come you will need to use the external Curl lib to be able to call the webservice.

Regards
Daws

Answer (score 0):

'Tizen Developer Site Documents' related your domain resides here:

[Internet and Content Downloads](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/internet-and-contents-downloads)

Check If these Documents are off your use:

---

[Connection Management Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/internet-and-contents-downloads/connection-management)

[Connection Management API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__NETWORK__CONNECTION__MODULE.html)

---

[Curl Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/internet-and-contents-downloads/curl)

[Curl API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__OPENSRC__CURL__FRAMEWORK.html)

---

[HTTP Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/internet-and-contents-downloads/http)

[HTTP API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__NETWORK__HTTP__MODULE.html)